Union of Three Subspaces Proof
Prove that the union of three subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if one of the subspaces contains the other two.
This is my proof by contradiction in the forward direction; I'm not sure it's correct.
(=>) Let $U_1, U_2,$ and $U_3$ be subspaces and $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3$ is a subspace.
Suppose by contradiction that one of the subspaces does not contain the other two, i.e., negate the following
($\forall x \in U_1 \cup U_2, x \in U_3$)
$x\in U_1\backslash U_2 \backslash U_3$, $y\in U_2 \backslash U_1 \backslash U_3$, meaning these elements live in $U_1 \cup U_2$ and $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$.
So, $x+y\in U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3$ by closure under addition since each element lives in the union of all three subspaces.
$x+y\in U_1$ or $x+y\in U_2$ or $x+y\in U_3$
$y$ can't be in $U_1$, x can't be in $U_2$, and $x+y$ can't be in $U_3$ as the elements chosen are not in $U_3$.
I'll end it there as I don't feel confident this was the correct approach.

$x \notin U$ and $y \notin U$ does not imply $x+y \notin U$. Consider the real plane, $U = {(a,0) : a \in \mathbb{R}}$, $x=(1,1), y=(1,-1)$.

Better use latex to type your question out, here’s the tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@aschepler I see the error in my logic. Thank you. Is there any way to salvage this?

The result is false in the general: it fails for the two dimensional vector space over the field of two elements. So the argument must use the cardinality of the field in some way.
